# watch logs while logged in as user

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, logging

I'm having the same issue as in [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201002/can-you-use-the-developer-console-while-logged-in-as-another-user-and-access-inf), where I need to be logged in as a test user with my app's permission set (and not higher), but I need see the logs to figure out why Calvin is successful, but Hobbs (with the same perm set) is not.

@sfdcfox answered the question -- no you can't open dev console while logged as a user (who wouldn't have those privileges).

I tried tracking it using sfdx force:apex:log:tail -- but the logs are tied to the login instance of the sys admin, and they go dead when I log in as a user.

Any ideas how I can check logs (or go back after the fact) to track what's happening while logged in as a test user?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using two different browsers (or alternatively, one normal browser and one browser in incognito/private mode)?

If you open another tab, the new tab will be the same user as the existing tab.  However, if you use a different browser or incognito/private mode, then you can log in as a different user.

Comment: I don't have a problem having the test user open while having the admin user open. The challenge is that the logs seem tied to the admin user -- they don't run on the test user account. And the test user account doesn't have the needed permissions to open the developer console (and assigning such permissions defeats the purpose of the test.)

Comment: When you are logged in as the admin user, have you tried using the Setup->Debug Logs and setting up debug logs for the test user?  This won't give you real time debugging, but will give you debug logs to review.